# Execute Script in Syslinux

Tags: boot, syslinux

I want to execute a script in Syslinux. Is this possible?

To be more specific: I want to write a one-time-windows-boot-script that does the following:

1. reboot into windows,
2. on the next reboot: reboot into Linux.

I thought, this should be possible by writing for (1) a script that sets my Windows partition as default in `syslinux.cfg` and for (2) a script that sets the Linux partition as default again.

As far as I understand Syslinux, I can only set options in the configuration but not execute scripts.. would something like this be possible with Syslinux or another bootmanager?

PS: I intent to use this with MBR.

Comment: I have got exactly the same usecase, have you got an answer in the meantime. changing the syslinux.cfg from within windows 7 may help, but ext2fs or similar did not work successfully so far. best regards
Uwe Damm

Comment: Hi Uwe, no, nothing so far.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a script in Linux that gets executed at shutdown and alters syslinux.cfg accordingly. That's for the 1st part. For the second part, maybe doing the same is possible with Windows, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: But this would alter `syslinux.cfg` on every reboot of Linux